# python jquery autocomplete on google app engine

Tags: jquery, python, google-app-engine, autocomplete

I have a python script, with a function inside that can, given a query, will output a few results taken from a massive dataset, too big to put in a jquery script in plain text format. How can I use jquery/javascript or whatever to make a very simply auto-complete search box. I have spent all day trying to get things to work and have had no luck with what I am trying to do.

Also- if it helps, this must be able to work on google app engine

Comment: So why can't we see what you've spent all day doing? You must have some code to show for all that. What exactly is not working?

Comment: I have been trying to get a jquery script where I can add textboxes several times to work with an autocomplete script. I have been able to get both seperatly, but I have not been able to get the autocomplete script to work from a pythons script spitting out results. All I was able to get to work was an autocomplete script that took results from an array on the same script.

Answer (score 0):

Have the JavaScript send an AJAX request to the server whenever someone types into the textbox.  Then when that responds with results from the server, you simply display them on the client.

[Take a look at this question here and its answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887266/how-to-return-and-use-an-array-of-strings-from-a-jquery-ajax-call)